How to Develop a Daily Habit of Critical Thinking and Writing During PhD?
StackExchange community!
I'm currently in my third year of a PhD program focused on geometrical fluid dynamics. As my research often involves complex coding and theoretical work, I face frequent periods where my code doesn't run as expected. During these times, I want to maintain productivity and continue intellectual growth.
I'm considering developing a daily habit of critical thinking and writing to enhance my problem-solving skills and give purpose to my days, even when the coding isn't going smoothly. I’m looking for effective strategies to integrate this into my daily routine.
Here are some specific questions I have:

What are effective techniques to incorporate critical thinking and writing into a daily academic routine?
How can I choose topics that will be intellectually stimulating and relevant to my field?
Does anyone have experience with balancing this kind of reflective practice with intense technical research?

I'd appreciate any advice or insights from those who have navigated similar challenges during their PhD or in their professional careers.
Thank you!

Your questions seem inconsistent with your problem. Why not just focus on getting the code correct?

Please also try to focus on one question instead of several in one post. The second one in particular may be too field-specific to be a good fit here.

@Buffy: My read on this is that the OP’s work involves extended stretches of detailed low-level technical work, and that they have correctly identified that broader intellectual thinking can suffer during these times of intense focus, and are looking for advise on work patterns that support maintaining their higher-level thinking.
